# Replacing the text which appear when Navigation Pane (Stemasoft) is minimized in WPF

Tags: wpf, navigation, pane

How to replace the text which appear when Navigation Pane is minimized in WPF based on the selected navigation pane item. Navigationpane used here is the navigation pane available from stemasoft.com  with its dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the BarTitle attribute

```
<stema:NavigationPane BarTitle="My title">
   <stema:NavigationPaneItem Header="Item 1">
      <local:MyControl/>
   </stema:NavigationPaneItem>
</stema:NavigationPane>
```

You can also specify an image for every item.

Comment: This Header will be displayed only when Navigation Pane is expanded.But I need to display the text(instaed of displaying 'Navigation Pane') when it is minimized.